# Unable to restore custom object of class "MeanMetricWrapper" in tf.keras.models.load_model despite not using any custom metrics

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I just spent a long time waiting for a Keras model to train, I saved it with tf.keras.models.save_model thinking I'd be able to load it back up easily but It's not working. The error message is

```
ValueError: Unable to restore custom object of class "MeanMetricWrapper" (type _tf_keras_metric). Please make sure that this class is included in the `custom_objects` arg when calling `load_model()`. Also, check that the class implements `get_config` and `from_config`.

Complete metadata: {'class_name': 'MeanMetricWrapper', 'name': 'loss', 'dtype': 'float32', 'config': {'name': 'loss', 'dtype': 'float32'}, 'shared_object_id': 12}
```

I am not actually using any custom metrics, I am using a custom model class which inherits from keras.Model and overwrites its **init** and train_step methods. The new **init** is just

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.pool = kwargs["pool"]
        del kwargs["pool"]

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

To allow me to pass in a multiprocessing Pool for use in the train step

I configured the model like this

```
model = CustomModel(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, pool=pool)
model.compile(optimizer="adam", metrics=["loss"])
model.fit([0]*1024*32, [0]*1024*32, epochs=20, batch_size=1024)

tf.keras.models.save_model(model, "C:\\src\\models\\model")
```

(I don't actually use the input x and y data in my custom train_step)

If I try

```
tf.keras.models.load_model("C:\\src\\models\\model", custom_objects={"MeanMetricWrapper": tf.metrics.MeanMetricWrapper})
```

It fails with the same error and if I try

```
tf.keras.models.load_model("C:\\src\\models\\model", custom_objects={"CustomModel": CustomModel})
```

The error becomes

```
  File "C:\Users\...\venv\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\trackable\base.py", line 204, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Functional.__init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'inputs' and 'outputs'
```

I'm running on Windows 10 using PyCharm, using tensorflow-intel from Pip. As I said a lot of training went in to this model so if there's any way to salvage it I'd be very greateful for the help, thanks